# Showing/Closing forms in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im developing an application using wpf template I have these 2 windows:
MainWindow.xaml and
JungleTimer.vb which is a Windows Form

I have a button in my main windows which shows JungleTimer form using this code:

```
Dim JungleTimer As New JungleTimer
        JungleTimer.Show()
```

But as you see, clicking this button multiple times will show multiple JungleTime form.
I tried to use this code to check if JungleTimer is visible but it doesn't work:

```
Dim JungleTimer As New JungleTimer
        If JungleTimer.Visible = False Then
            JungleTimer.Show()
        End If
```

I also need the code to close the JungleTimer form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are creating a new JungleTimer each time you click the button you will always get a new instance of the window. What you need to do is declare a field within the class of the type JungleTimer. Initially this will be null (Nothing). When you click the button, check if this field has a value or is still null. If still null, set it to a new JungleTimer and show it. If it isn't null, activate the existing window without creating a new instance. you'll also need to detect when the window closes so that you can set the field back to null.

For a demo, create a new WPF application with two windows, MainWindow (the main window) and JungleTimer.

XAML for MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Width="100" Height="30" Click="Jungle_Click">Jungle Me</Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="30" Click="DeJungle_Click">De-Jungle Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

VB for MainWindow (sorry if it's clumsy, I haven't done VB for ten years or so):

```
Class MainWindow

Private WithEvents _jungleTimer As JungleTimer

Private Sub Jungle_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    If _jungleTimer Is Nothing Then
        _jungleTimer = New JungleTimer
        _jungleTimer.Show()
    Else
        _jungleTimer.Activate()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DeJungle_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    If Not _jungleTimer Is Nothing Then
        _jungleTimer.Hide()
        _jungleTimer = Nothing
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CloseHandler() Handles _jungleTimer.Closed

    _jungleTimer = Nothing

End Sub
End Class
```

XAML for JungleWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="JungleTimer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="JungleTimer" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        Jungle!
    </Label>
</Grid>
```